# Accessing Page Fields In Search Results

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to style search results and I can't figure out how to access any of the page properties (like title) in the search results, except the html.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You mean in CSS? Using your browser dev tools, it should be easy to figure out a good selector, but it's hard to give a generic answer as that entirely depends on the theme you're using. With theme machine, that could be: `.search-results .content-item h1`.